# Magento2 pub/static permissions

Tags: magento2, http-status-403

I'm getting 403 errors in my console for calendar.css, mixins.js, require.js. Is it permission or ownership issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use the following file/folder permissions and haven't run into issues so far.

```
cd <MAGENTO_INSTALL_DIR>
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: In what folder are you running this? Magento Root?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that part..

Comment: I get this error with this: find: paths must precede expression: find
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: Is there a document that you reference for this?

Comment: I believe I used or modified and used the settings suggested by the Magento for a while now.

Here's the Magento link for ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/rc_perms.html

Comment: When I ran that I get :operation not permitted

Comment: Your SSH user needs to be the owner to be able to change the permissions.

Comment: I tried as the owner and the group. I cant delete the "frontend" folder and the deployed code text file.

Comment: It seems the "frontend" folder was generated by executing php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command while logged in as different user and the current one doesn't have the permissions to delete the frontend folder.